# XSLT for Recursion

Tags: xslt

I have below xml and i need we need to convert to Expected Output xml using xslt which we have acheived

In the input xml i have referenced as topmost node which has subnodes as follows:

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
<referenced>
  <name>PocTree/PocTree.services:getReferencesForServices</name>
  <LOCK_STATUS>3</LOCK_STATUS>
  <type>
    <svc_type>flow</svc_type>
    <svc_subtype>default</svc_subtype>
  </type>
  <path/>
  <isPub>false</isPub>
  <isNotification>false</isNotification>
  <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
  <status>reference</status>
  <reference>
    <name>WmRoot/wm.server.ns.dependency:getReferenced</name>
    <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
    <type>
      <svc_type>java</svc_type>
      <svc_subtype>unknown</svc_subtype>
    </type>
    <path>/Flow Path;1.0/INVOKE;0</path>
    <isPub>false</isPub>
    <isNotification>false</isNotification>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
    <status>resolved</status>
  </reference>
  <reference>
    <name>WmPublic/pub.xml:documentToXMLString</name>
    <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
    <type>
      <svc_type>java</svc_type>
      <svc_subtype>unknown</svc_subtype>
    </type>
    <path>/Flow Path;1.0/INVOKE;1</path>
    <isPub>false</isPub>
    <isNotification>false</isNotification>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
    <status>resolved</status>
  </reference>
  <reference>
    <name>PocTree/PocTree.services:jkl</name>
    <LOCK_STATUS>3</LOCK_STATUS>
    <type>
      <svc_type>xsltservice</svc_type>
      <svc_subtype>unknown</svc_subtype>
    </type>
    <path>/Flow Path;1.0/INVOKE;2</path>
    <isPub>false</isPub>
    <isNotification>false</isNotification>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
    <status>resolved</status>
  </reference>
  <reference>
    <name>WmPublic/pub.xml:xmlStringToXMLNode</name>
    <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
    <type>
      <svc_type>java</svc_type>
      <svc_subtype>unknown</svc_subtype>
    </type>
    <path>/Flow Path;1.0/INVOKE;3</path>
    <isPub>false</isPub>
    <isNotification>false</isNotification>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
    <status>resolved</status>
  </reference>
  <reference>
    <name>WmPublic/pub.xml:xmlNodeToDocument</name>
    <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
    <type>
      <svc_type>java</svc_type>
      <svc_subtype>unknown</svc_subtype>
    </type>
    <path>/Flow Path;1.0/INVOKE;4</path>
    <isPub>false</isPub>
    <isNotification>false</isNotification>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
    <status>resolved</status>
  </reference>
  <reference>
    <name>PocTree/PocTree.services:ghi</name>
    <LOCK_STATUS>4</LOCK_STATUS>
    <type>
      <svc_type>xsltservice</svc_type>
      <svc_subtype>unknown</svc_subtype>
    </type>
    <path>/Flow Path;1.0/INVOKE;5</path>
    <isPub>false</isPub>
    <isNotification>false</isNotification>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
    <status>resolved</status>
  </reference>
  <reference>
    <name>WxPackageTree/WxPackageTree.doc:NodeInfo</name>
    <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
    <type>
      <type_name>record</type_name>
    </type>
    <path>/Service Path;1.0/signature;2;subPath;"/nodes;4;0;WxPackageTree.doc:NodeInfo"</path>
    <isPub>false</isPub>
    <isNotification>false</isNotification>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
    <status>reference</status>
    <reference>
      <name>WxPackageTree/WxPackageTree.doc:NodeInfo</name>
      <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
      <type>
        <type_name>record</type_name>
      </type>
      <path>/children;4;1;WxPackageTree.doc:NodeInfo</path>
      <isPub>false</isPub>
      <isNotification>false</isNotification>
      <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
      <status>recursive</status>
    </reference>
    <reference>
    <name>PocTree/PocTree.docs:nodeInfo</name>
    <LOCK_STATUS>4</LOCK_STATUS>
    <type>
      <type_name>record</type_name>
    </type>
    <path>/Flow Path;1.0/MAP;6/MAPCOPY;1/to_field;-2;subPath;"/nodeInfo;4;0;PocTree.docs:nodeInfo"</path>
    <path>/Flow Path;1.0/MAP;6/MAPCOPY;2/to_field;-2;subPath;"/nodeInfo;4;0;PocTree.docs:nodeInfo"</path>
    <path>/Flow Path;1.0/MAP;6/MAPCOPY;3/to_field;-2;subPath;"/nodeInfo;4;0;PocTree.docs:nodeInfo"</path>
    <isPub>false</isPub>
    <isNotification>false</isNotification>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
    <status>reference</status>
    <reference>
      <name>PocTree/PocTree.docs:nodeInfo</name>
      <LOCK_STATUS>4</LOCK_STATUS>
      <type>
        <type_name>record</type_name>
      </type>
      <path>/children;4;1;PocTree.docs:nodeInfo</path>
      <isPub>false</isPub>
      <isNotification>false</isNotification>
      <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
      <status>recursive</status>
    </reference>
  </reference>
  </reference>
</referenced>
```

XSLT written :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="x"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="referenced"/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="referenced | reference">
    <nodeInfo>
       <name>
         <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(name, '/')"/>
        </name>
        <rowId>
            <xsl:value-of select="generate-id()"/>
        </rowId>
        <parentId>
            <xsl:value-of select="generate-id(..)"/>
        </parentId>
<xsl:apply-templates select="isFlowServiceDisabled"/>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="type"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="isPub"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="isFlowServiceDisabled"/>
    </nodeInfo>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="reference"/>
</xsl:template>


 <xsl:template match="type[svc_type]">
        <type>
            <xsl:value-of select="svc_type" />
        </type>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="type[type_name]">
        <type>
            <xsl:value-of select="type_name" />
        </type>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="type[trigger_type]">
        <type>
            <xsl:value-of select="trigger_type" />
        </type>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="isFlowServiceDisabled" >

         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="isFlowServiceDisabled[contains(., 'false')]">
                <isFlowServiceDisabled>
                    <xsl:value-of select="isFlowServiceDisabled" />
                </isFlowServiceDisabled>
             </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise/>

        </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="reference[type/svc_type[not(contains(., 'flow') or contains(., 'java') or contains(., 'xsltservice'))]]" />


    <xsl:template match="reference[type/type_name[not(contains(., 'ConnectionData') or contains(., 'webServiceDescriptor'))]]" priority="2" />

    <xsl:template match="reference[type/trigger_type[not(contains(., 'jms-trigger') or contains(., 'broker-trigger'))]]" priority="2" />




</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Target XML im looking for

```
<nodeInfo>
    -
    -
    <rowId>1</rowId>
    <parentNodeId>0</parentNodeId>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
</nodeInfo>
<nodeInfo>
    -
    -
    <rowId>2</rowId>
    <parentNodeId>1</parentNodeId>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
</nodeInfo>
<nodeInfo>
    -
    -
    <rowId>3</rowId>
    <parentNodeId>1</parentNodeId>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
</nodeInfo>
<nodeInfo> 
    -
    -
    <rowId>4</rowId>
    <parentNodeId>1</parentNodeId>
     <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
</nodeInfo>
<nodeInfo>
    -
    -
    <rowId>5</rowId>
    <parentNodeId>4</parentNodeId>
   <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
</nodeInfo>
 <nodeInfo>
    -
    -
    <rowId>6</rowId>
    <parentNodeId>4</parentNodeId>
     <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
</nodeInfo>
<nodeInfo> 
    -
    -
    <rowId>7</rowId>
    <parentNodeId>1</parentNodeId>
     <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
</nodeInfo>
<nodeInfo>
    -
    -
    <rowId>8</rowId>
    <parentNodeId>7</parentNodeId>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
</nodeInfo>
<nodeInfo>
    -
    -
    <rowId>9</rowId>
    <parentNodeId>7</parentNodeId>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
</nodeInfo>
<nodeInfo>
    -
    -
    <rowId>10</rowId>
    <parentNodeId>9</parentNodeId>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
</nodeInfo>
```

Problem i am facing is that the condition written for tag `<isFlowServiceDisabled>` is not working as expected . Meaning I am getting the tag with empty value , not sure what is wrong with my XSLT . Apart from other conditions in XSLT , i also want to enforce a rule where if node `<isFlowServiceDisabled>` has a value of "false" only then include or else dont include.

Kindly advise what is causing me empty value.

Answer (score 1):

I think following should be fixed,

You don't need following template. Also you should not use xsl:choose here instead only  would do. Also you have added xsl:copy-of select="isFlowServiceDisabled" which will override your template call. I have removed it.

```
    <xsl:template match="isFlowServiceDisabled" >

     <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="isFlowServiceDisabled[contains(., 'false')]">
            <isFlowServiceDisabled>
                <xsl:value-of select="isFlowServiceDisabled" />
            </isFlowServiceDisabled>
         </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise/>

    </xsl:choose>

</xsl:template>
```

It should be done without template,

```
<xsl:if test="isFlowServiceDisabled = 'false'">
     <isFlowServiceDisabled>
           false
     </isFlowServiceDisabled>
</xsl:if>
```

EDIT : Updated XML and XSL with proper required output.
Check demo here : http://xsltransform.net/ejivdHb/8

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <referenced>
      <name>PocTree/PocTree.services:getReferencesForServices</name>
      <LOCK_STATUS>3</LOCK_STATUS>
      <type>
         <svc_type>flow</svc_type>
         <svc_subtype>default</svc_subtype>
      </type>
<path />
<isPub>false</isPub>
<isNotification>false</isNotification>
<isFlowServiceDisabled>true</isFlowServiceDisabled>
<status>reference</status>
<reference>
    <name>WmRoot/wm.server.ns.dependency:getReferenced</name>
    <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
    <type>
        <svc_type>java</svc_type>
        <svc_subtype>unknown</svc_subtype>
    </type>
    <path>/Flow Path;1.0/INVOKE;0</path>
    <isPub>false</isPub>
    <isNotification>false</isNotification>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
    <status>resolved</status>
</reference>
<reference>
    <name>WmPublic/pub.xml:documentToXMLString</name>
    <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
    <type>
        <svc_type>java</svc_type>
        <svc_subtype>unknown</svc_subtype>
    </type>
    <path>/Flow Path;1.0/INVOKE;1</path>
    <isPub>false</isPub>
    <isNotification>false</isNotification>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
    <status>resolved</status>
</reference>
<reference>
    <name>PocTree/PocTree.services:jkl</name>
    <LOCK_STATUS>3</LOCK_STATUS>
    <type>
        <svc_type>xsltservice</svc_type>
        <svc_subtype>unknown</svc_subtype>
    </type>
    <path>/Flow Path;1.0/INVOKE;2</path>
    <isPub>false</isPub>
    <isNotification>false</isNotification>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>true</isFlowServiceDisabled>
    <status>resolved</status>
</reference>
<reference>
    <name>WmPublic/pub.xml:xmlStringToXMLNode</name>
    <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
    <type>
        <svc_type>java</svc_type>
        <svc_subtype>unknown</svc_subtype>
    </type>
    <path>/Flow Path;1.0/INVOKE;3</path>
    <isPub>false</isPub>
    <isNotification>false</isNotification>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
    <status>resolved</status>
</reference>
<reference>
    <name>WmPublic/pub.xml:xmlNodeToDocument</name>
    <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
    <type>
        <svc_type>java</svc_type>
        <svc_subtype>unknown</svc_subtype>
    </type>
    <path>/Flow Path;1.0/INVOKE;4</path>
    <isPub>false</isPub>
    <isNotification>false</isNotification>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
    <status>resolved</status>
</reference>
<reference>
    <name>PocTree/PocTree.services:ghi</name>
    <LOCK_STATUS>4</LOCK_STATUS>
    <type>
        <svc_type>xsltservice</svc_type>
        <svc_subtype>unknown</svc_subtype>
    </type>
    <path>/Flow Path;1.0/INVOKE;5</path>
    <isPub>false</isPub>
    <isNotification>false</isNotification>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
    <status>resolved</status>
</reference>
<reference>
    <name>WxPackageTree/WxPackageTree.doc:NodeInfo</name>
    <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
    <type>
        <type_name>record</type_name>
    </type>
    <path>/Service Path;1.0/signature;2;subPath;"/nodes;4;0;WxPackageTree.doc:NodeInfo"</path>
    <isPub>false</isPub>
    <isNotification>false</isNotification>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
    <status>reference</status>
    <reference>
        <name>WxPackageTree/WxPackageTree.doc:NodeInfo</name>
        <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
        <type>
            <type_name>record</type_name>
        </type>
        <path>/children;4;1;WxPackageTree.doc:NodeInfo</path>
        <isPub>false</isPub>
        <isNotification>false</isNotification>
        <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
        <status>recursive</status>
    </reference>
    <reference>
        <name>PocTree/PocTree.docs:nodeInfo</name>
        <LOCK_STATUS>4</LOCK_STATUS>
        <type>
            <type_name>record</type_name>
        </type>
        <path>/Flow Path;1.0/MAP;6/MAPCOPY;1/to_field;-2;subPath;"/nodeInfo;4;0;PocTree.docs:nodeInfo"</path>
        <path>/Flow Path;1.0/MAP;6/MAPCOPY;2/to_field;-2;subPath;"/nodeInfo;4;0;PocTree.docs:nodeInfo"</path>
        <path>/Flow Path;1.0/MAP;6/MAPCOPY;3/to_field;-2;subPath;"/nodeInfo;4;0;PocTree.docs:nodeInfo"</path>
        <isPub>false</isPub>
        <isNotification>false</isNotification>
        <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
        <status>reference</status>
        <reference>
            <name>PocTree/PocTree.docs:nodeInfo</name>
            <LOCK_STATUS>4</LOCK_STATUS>
            <type>
                <type_name>record</type_name>
            </type>
            <path>/children;4;1;PocTree.docs:nodeInfo</path>
            <isPub>false</isPub>
            <isNotification>false</isNotification>
            <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
            <status>recursive</status>
        </reference>
    </reference>
</reference>
```

XSL

```
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="x"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
     <root>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="referenced"/>
     </root>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="referenced | reference">
    <nodeInfo>
     <name>
       <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(name, '/')"/>
     </name>
    <rowId>
        <xsl:value-of select="generate-id()"/>
    </rowId>
    <parentId>
        <xsl:value-of select="generate-id(..)"/>
    </parentId>

       <xsl:apply-templates select="type"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="isPub"/>

     <xsl:if test="isFlowServiceDisabled = 'false'">
        <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
    </xsl:if>
</nodeInfo>
<xsl:apply-templates select="reference"/>
</xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="type[svc_type]">
    <type>
        <xsl:value-of select="svc_type" />
    </type>
  </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="type[type_name]">
    <type>
        <xsl:value-of select="type_name" />
    </type>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="type[trigger_type]">
    <type>
        <xsl:value-of select="trigger_type" />
    </type>
   </xsl:template>



    <xsl:template match="reference[type/svc_type[not(contains(., 'flow') or contains(., 'java') or contains(., 'xsltservice'))]]" />


     <xsl:template match="reference[type/type_name[not(contains(., 'ConnectionData') or contains(., 'webServiceDescriptor'))]]" priority="2" />

     <xsl:template match="reference[type/trigger_type[not(contains(., 'jms-trigger') or contains(., 'broker-trigger'))]]" priority="2" />

  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for your inputs . Well again i have a problem : when <isServiceDisabled> is having value "true" then in my output xml it is coming with empty value where as i want the entire <reference> to me skipped if <isServiceDisabled> is true. How to tweak the xslt for this ?

Comment: @Nis please accept my answer for your original question. However for your new requirement you can check for isServiceDisabled similar to isFlowServiceDisabled and put reference block into it

Comment: My bad i spelt the tag name wrong . I was actually referring to <isFlowServiceDisabled > . As i mentioned earlier if it is having value true , in the Output xml i want the the entire <nodeInfo> to be skipped . How do i acheive this ?